# How to check if variable exists and then print it in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Here is my example:

```
<img data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" class="tip"
     data-original-title="{{user.dbInfo.city}}, {{user.dbInfo.country_name}}"
     src="https://countryflags.io/{{user.dbInfo.country}}/flat/24.png">
```

and I want to show the `{{user.dbInfo.city}},` only if the variable exists. In some cases there is no city.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Have you already tried *ngIf ?

Comment: In this case it is better to build the whole string in component and then pass it to `data-original-title`, because template solution might be weird

Comment: Did you try `user.dbInfo.hasOwnProperty('city')` in `ngIf `??

Comment: have you tried *ngIf=" user.dbInfo.city !=  ',' "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows.

```
 <img data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" class="tip"
    data-original-title="{{ user.dbInfo.city ? user.dbInfo.city + ',' + user.dbInfo.country_name : user.dbInfo.country_name }}"
    src="https://countryflags.io/{{user.dbInfo.country}}/flat/24.png">
```

Comment: I get this error `http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$parse/ueoe?p0=user.dbInfo.city%20%3F%20user.dbInfo.city%20%2B%20'%2C'%20%2B%20user.dbInfo.country_name%20%3F%20user.dbInfo.country_name`

Comment: sorry small mistake i have added extra ?. can you check now ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to display another data-original-title based on the existence of the variable.

```js
<ng-container *ngIf="user.dbInfo.city">
    <img data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" class="tip" data-original-title="{{user.dbInfo.city}}, {{user.dbInfo.country_name}}" src="https://countryflags.io/{{user.dbInfo.country}}/flat/24.png">
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="!user.dbInfo.city">
    <img data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" class="tip" data-original-title="{{user.dbInfo.country_name}}" src="https://countryflags.io/{{user.dbInfo.country}}/flat/24.png">
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Hello, I am using Angular with ng-if version

Comment: too complicated for such small problem

Comment: @LuninRoman If you have a better way to do it, feel free to propose your own answer. That is a way to achieve what is asked.

Answer (score 0):

For things like this, I always create a method in my component class, something like `formatImageOriginalTitle(dbInfo)` which would look like this:

```ts
formatImageOriginalTitle(dbInfo) {
    return dbInfo.city ? `${dbInfo.city}, ${dbInfo.country_name}` : dbInfo.country_name;
}
```

Then in the markup:

```html
<img ... data-original-title="formatImageOriginalTitle(user.dbInfo)" ... />
```

If this is something you may reuse in other places, you may create a [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) instead.

Comment: Here's a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aqnmba

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate it in the template itself by using property binding.

> [attr.original-title]="(user.dbInfo.city ? user.dbInfo.city + ',' : ' ') + user.dbInfo.country_name"

Try like this:

```
<img data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" class="tip"
 [attr.original-title]="(user.dbInfo.city ? user.dbInfo.city + ',' : '') + user.dbInfo.country_name"
 src="https://countryflags.io/{{user.dbInfo.country}}/flat/24.png">
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5inwwj?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Hello, for this `data-original-title="{{user.dbInfo.city}} + ({{user.dbInfo.city}} ? ',' : '') + {{user.dbInfo.country_name}}"` I get this result `Athens + (Athens ? ',' : '') + Greece`

Comment: But I need it to be like `Athens, Greece`

Comment: Use `property binding`

Comment: I don't know what property binding is

Comment: `[attr.original-title]=""` this is property binding. `{{}}` is interpolation. Try `[attr.original-title]="(user.dbInfo.city ? user.dbInfo.city + ',' : ' ') + user.dbInfo.country_name"`

Comment: Can you check the demo I  shared?

Answer (score 0):

A function as @MattU said can help you

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.user1 = {
    dbInfo: {
      city: 'CITY',
      country: 'be'
    }
  };

  $scope.user2 = {
    dbInfo: {
      country: 'be'
    }
  };


  $scope.getTitle = function(obj) {
    if (obj.dbInfo.hasOwnProperty('city')) {
      return obj.dbInfo.city + ',' + obj.dbInfo.country;
    }
    return obj.dbInfo.country;
  };

});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <img data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" class="tip" data-original-title="{{getTitle(user1)}}" src="https://www.countryflags.io/{{user1.dbInfo.country}}/flat/24.png">

  <img data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" class="tip" data-original-title="{{getTitle(user2)}}" src="https://www.countryflags.io/{{user2.dbInfo.country}}/flat/24.png">
</body>

</html>
```